# Install Hive JDBC Drivers on a Wildfly Server for creating a datasource

Tags: java, hive, wildfly, cloudera

I'm having trouble trying to connect a Wildfly App with a Hive Remote DB.
If I package the whole thing as a JAR, it works like a charm, but, the moment I include it in the war file, the problems starts.

When I include the hive-jdbc package in the war, the server informs me that he can't access to the Timeline class and the whole app refuses to start.

So I tryied to add Hive as a Datasource in order to isolate the need of the package inside the app, but, I tryied almost everything and it didn't worked.

Does anyone have a similar experience or can help me?

Comment: Did you try with `hive-hdbc-standalone`?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Yeah and worked, thanks!